# Intellij plugin - How to create an action that fires on a specific text hover

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to create a plugin for my company so that an action is fired on hover, and only in a specific case (a specific and partially constant string).

Example:

Say I have an XML/HTML file with some attributes:

```
<attribute someAction="something" fieldName="unknown"/>
<attribute width="10" fieldName="whoKnows"/>
<attribute fieldName="incognito" **resourceCode="007"**/>
```

I want that when hovering above the `resourceCode="007"` part, my action will be triggered. In all other cases, I don't want to do anything.
The `resourceCode=` is constant, and the value itself is a variable that I need to use in my action.

I went over the Q&A here, and in other places, and tried the official documentation, but with no success.

Comment: Bootstrap or ASP.NET? Is this a jQuery or JavaScript issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement custom [documentationProvider extension](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/documentation.html):

> Custom languages can use the com.intellij.lang.documentationProvider
> extension point (EP) to show documentation for functions, methods,
> classes, or other constructs right inside the IDE. Accessing the
> documentation is done by calling View | Quick Documentation or
> hovering over a symbol, which will open a popup to show type
> information, parameters, usage descriptions, or examples. The source
> of the documentation contents can vary. Often it is extracted from
> comments (e.g. JavaDoc comments) in the source code, but it's also
> possible to access **external resources like web pages**.

Example implementation at [PropertiesDocumentationProvider.java](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-6ed4281aa53e1672d2e5870243c6606bb48afc84/plugins/properties/src/com/intellij/lang/properties/PropertiesDocumentationProvider.java?_gl=1*1ee8k0m*_ga*MTgzMzI4NjY2MC4xNjIzNzQzMjc4*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY1NTQ5MTEwMS4xOC4xLjE2NTU0OTExNDcuMA..&_ga=2.112164484.1056399452.1655464139-1833286660.1623743278) and [ThemeJsonDocumentationProvider.java](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-6ed4281aa53e1672d2e5870243c6606bb48afc84/plugins/devkit/devkit-core/src/themes/ThemeJsonDocumentationProvider.java?_gl=1*il0ued*_ga*MTgzMzI4NjY2MC4xNjIzNzQzMjc4*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY1NTQ5MTEwMS4xOC4xLjE2NTU0OTEyMjkuMA..&_ga=2.11490996.1056399452.1655464139-1833286660.1623743278) that you can customize it for your own needs

[Inlay Hints](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/inlay-hints.html) and [Code Inspections and Intentions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/code-inspections-and-intentions.html) may be useful too.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Do you know an open source example of a plugin which uses these APIs?

Comment: Examples section provided link to full implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean an example of a complete plugin, which can be download and installed in IntelliJ for better understanding how everything is connected.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/intellij-platform-explorer/extensions

Comment: You have to do some coding, you should implement `generateDoc` method based on your needs.

Comment: @Meo more specifically https://plugins.jetbrains.com/intellij-platform-explorer/extensions?extensions=com.intellij.documentationProvider ?